# How will I get the value of label attribute in jquery

Tags: jquery, razor, model-view-controller

```
<td>
    @Html.Label(item.NAME, new { id = @item.SUPERID + "Name" })
</td>
<td>
    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.NAMEA, new { htmlAttributes 
    = new { @class = "form-control", id = @item.SUPERID + "Namea" 
  } })
 </td>
 <td>                
    <button Type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" 
     id="COPY"  OnClick=button_onclick("@item.SUPERID") >Copy From 
     SAP <span class="fa fa-copy"></span></button>
</td>
@section scripts
{
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
    </script>

     <script>
         $('#xyz').DataTable({
            "bFilter": false,
            "bLengthchange":false   
        });
        function button_onclick(ID) {      
          $("#ID +Namea").val()= $("#ID +Name").val();     
        alert();
        }
    </script>
}
```

this is the code I have written.
Here I am trying to assign the value in label to that of html         "editorfor" element.Can Anybody help me with below.

Comment: A label does not have a value. With your code, it will have the same value in your input element , as what your label text is.

Comment: thanks for your comments,I used another approach to get the values.Happy Coding :)